# Error con Insert en Postgresql en C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un problema que no puedo resolver por que no veo el error.
Estoy desarrollando un simple proyecto en C#, cuando ejecuto un procedimiento almacenado de Postgresql (Insert):

```
pgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select insertclientes(" + @idcuenta_corriente + "," +
                "'" + @nombre+ "','" + @apellido + "'," +
                "'" + @domicilio + "'," + @idprovincia + "," +
                "" + @idlocalidad + "," + @idtipo_identificador + "," +
                "" + @numero_identificador + "," + @idcondicion_iva + "," +
                "'" + @email + "'," + @telefono + "," + @idretenciones + "," + @idlistaprecios + ");", Connections());
```

No se ve reflejado en la base de datos, es decir que no realiza el insert, pero tampoco me muestra algun error.
Para ver la salida del programa y imprimir la consola sql realice esto:

```
  Console.Write("select insertclientes(" + @idcuenta_corriente + "," +
                "'" + @nombre + "','" + @apellido + "'," +
                "'" + @domicilio + "'," + @idprovincia + "," +
                "" + @idlocalidad + "," + @idtipo_identificador + "," +
                "" + @numero_identificador + "," + @idcondicion_iva + "," +
                "'" + @email + "'," + @telefono + "," + @idretenciones + "," + @idlistaprecios + ");");
```

Me da como resultado:

```
select insertclientes(1,'dfhsfhdfshsdfhsdf','dfhfhfh','ghfkghfkfgh',0,0,0,444,0,'hkjhkhjkhgjk',111,2,2);El programa '[15836] Contable1.exe: Seguimiento de programa' terminó con código 0 (0x0).
```

Ahora si copio la consulta y la esjecuto desde PgAdmin se inserta satisfactoriamente el dato.

Paso el script completo de la capa datos:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//contableEntidad
using System.Windows;
using contableEntidad;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Npgsql;

namespace contableDatos
{
    public class DContable
    {

        public NpgsqlConnection Connections() {


            var stringConnection = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=admin;Database=contable";
            NpgsqlConnection SQLPostgres = new NpgsqlConnection(stringConnection);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringConnection))
            {

                try
                {

                    SQLPostgres = new NpgsqlConnection(stringConnection);
                    SQLPostgres.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("conectado ");

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    SQLPostgres.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("NO conectado ");
                }
            }

            return SQLPostgres;

        }
        //Listar clientes
        public DataTable  Clientes() {

            //NpgsqlDataAdapter dataContable = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("select listarclientes()", SQLPostgres);
            //NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * from cliente", Connections());
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            NpgsqlDataAdapter Da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from cliente", Connections());
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
           // DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Da.Fill(Dt);
            return Dt;

        }

        //Listar 
        public List<Paises> Paiseslist()
        {

            List<Paises> _lista = new List<Paises>();
           // List<string> listaPaises = new List<string>();

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM pais", Connections());
            ///// //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            NpgsqlDataAdapter Da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT  * FROM pais", Connections());

            NpgsqlDataReader _reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            Da.Fill(Dt);


            for (var i = 0; _reader.Read(); i++) {

                //listaPaises.Add(_reader[0].ToString());
                Paises paises = new Paises();
                paises.codigo = _reader.GetInt32(0);
                paises.pais = _reader.GetString(1);

                // listaPaises.Add(_reader[2].ToString());

                _lista.Add(paises);

            }
            return _lista;
            //return listaPaises;


        }
        //Listar identificador

        public List<Tidentificacion> TipoIdentificador()
        {
            List<Tidentificacion> _lista = new List<Tidentificacion>();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM public.tipo_identificador", Connections());
            NpgsqlDataReader _reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            for (var i = 0; _reader.Read(); i++)
            { 
                Tidentificacion tidenti = new Tidentificacion();
                tidenti.idtipo_identificacion = _reader.GetInt32(0);
                tidenti.identificador = _reader.GetString(1);
                _lista.Add(tidenti);
            }
            return _lista;
        }
        //Listar codigo de iva

        public List<Codigoiva> codigoIVA()
        {
            List<Codigoiva> _lista = new List<Codigoiva>();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM public.codiva", Connections());
            NpgsqlDataReader _reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            for (var i = 0; _reader.Read(); i++)
            {
                Codigoiva civa = new Codigoiva();
                civa.codigo_iva = _reader.GetInt32(0);
                civa.descripcion_iva = _reader.GetString(1);
                _lista.Add(civa);
            }
            return _lista;
        }
        //localidad
        public List<Localidad> listLocalidad()
        {
            List<Localidad> _lista = new List<Localidad>();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM public.localidad", Connections());
            NpgsqlDataReader _reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            for (var i = 0; _reader.Read(); i++)
            {
                Localidad llocalidad = new Localidad();
                llocalidad.idlocalidad = _reader.GetInt32(0);
                llocalidad.cod_descripcion = _reader.GetString(1);
                _lista.Add(llocalidad);
            }
            return _lista;
        }
        //provincia
        public List<Provincia> listProvincia()
        {
            List<Provincia> _lista = new List<Provincia>();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM public.provincia", Connections());
            NpgsqlDataReader _reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            for (var i = 0; _reader.Read(); i++)
            {
                Provincia lprovincia = new Provincia();
                lprovincia.id_provincia = _reader.GetInt32(0);
                lprovincia.provincia = _reader.GetString(1);
                _lista.Add(lprovincia);
            }
            return _lista;
        }

        public void insertClient(
            int idcuenta_corriente,
            string nombre,
            string apellido,
            string domicilio,
            int idprovincia,
            int idlocalidad,
            int idtipo_identificador,
            int numero_identificador,
            int idcondicion_iva, 
            string email, 
            int telefono, 
            int idretenciones, 
            int idlistaprecios) {

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select insertclientes(" + @idcuenta_corriente + "," +
                "'" + @nombre+ "','" + @apellido + "'," +
                "'" + @domicilio + "'," + @idprovincia + "," +
                "" + @idlocalidad + "," + @idtipo_identificador + "," +
                "" + @numero_identificador + "," + @idcondicion_iva + "," +
                "'" + @email + "'," + @telefono + "," + @idretenciones + "," + @idlistaprecios + ");", Connections());
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            Console.Write("select insertclientes(" + @idcuenta_corriente + "," +
                "'" + @nombre + "','" + @apellido + "'," +
                "'" + @domicilio + "'," + @idprovincia + "," +
                "" + @idlocalidad + "," + @idtipo_identificador + "," +
                "" + @numero_identificador + "," + @idcondicion_iva + "," +
                "'" + @email + "'," + @telefono + "," + @idretenciones + "," + @idlistaprecios + ");");
        }

    }
 }
```

Para el que no quiera ver el script completo este es el método que utilizo para realizar el insert con el procedimiento.

```
 public void insertClient(
            int idcuenta_corriente,
            string nombre,
            string apellido,
            string domicilio,
            int idprovincia,
            int idlocalidad,
            int idtipo_identificador,
            int numero_identificador,
            int idcondicion_iva, 
            string email, 
            int telefono, 
            int idretenciones, 
            int idlistaprecios) {

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select insertclientes(" + @idcuenta_corriente + "," +
                "'" + @nombre+ "','" + @apellido + "'," +
                "'" + @domicilio + "'," + @idprovincia + "," +
                "" + @idlocalidad + "," + @idtipo_identificador + "," +
                "" + @numero_identificador + "," + @idcondicion_iva + "," +
                "'" + @email + "'," + @telefono + "," + @idretenciones + "," + @idlistaprecios + ");", Connections());
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            Console.Write("select insertclientes(" + @idcuenta_corriente + "," +
                "'" + @nombre + "','" + @apellido + "'," +
                "'" + @domicilio + "'," + @idprovincia + "," +
                "" + @idlocalidad + "," + @idtipo_identificador + "," +
                "" + @numero_identificador + "," + @idcondicion_iva + "," +
                "'" + @email + "'," + @telefono + "," + @idretenciones + "," + @idlistaprecios + ");");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Perdone, pero: `insertclientes` ¿es un procedimiento almacenado?. Le recomiendo 2 cosas: 1) En una variable string escriba la sentencia SQL a ejecutar "INSERT, stored procedured, etc". y muéstrela en consola - puede que tenga errores tipográficos, 2) use `try/catch` para capturar los detalles del error. [Mira cómo usar el try/catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions).

Comment: Algo muy importante, inserta los parámetros de tu consulta  usando el `cmd.Parameters` es una muy buena costumbre y te evitaras problemas de seguridad

Answer (score 1):

Primero no hay objeto que inicialice la conexión por eso es posible que el query no se ejecute,ademas los parámetros con @ no están siendo comparados con los definidos en el método,reo que podrías llamar de forma implícita los parámetros que estas definiendo en el método

```
  public void insertClient(
            int idcuenta_corriente,
            string nombre,
            string apellido,
            string domicilio,
            int idprovincia,
            int idlocalidad,
            int idtipo_identificador,
            int numero_identificador,
            int idcondicion_iva, 
            string email, 
            int telefono, 
            int idretenciones, 
            int idlistaprecios) {

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select insertclientes(" + idcuenta_corriente+ "," +
                "'" + nombre+ "','" + apellido + "'," +
                "'" + domicilio + "'," + idprovincia + "," +
                "" + idlocalidad + "," + idtipo_identificador + "," +
                "" + numero_identificador + "," + idcondicion_iva + "," +
                "'" + email + "'," + telefono + "," + idretenciones + "," + idlistaprecios + ");", Connections());
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          NpgsqlDataReader pgreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }

    }
```

En caso quieras usar el @parametroX tendrías  que agregar unas lineas mas donde dices ("@paramatroX",parametro) ejemplo:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre);
```

Luego debes poner un ibjeto de Npgsql para que ejecute el query.

```
NpgsqlDataReader pgreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Hay un problema parecido solucionado en este link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112835/execute-stored-procedure-with-parameters-postgresql

Comment: Excelente explicación!!! @Hans Rolando Ramos